# Dojo Gauges - can I restrict the settable values?

Tags: javascript, dojo, gauge

I have an interactive dojox gauge with a range from 0 - 100. But I only want my users to be able to move the needle to 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100. Is that possible?

```
                // create the gauge
            var gauge = new dojox.gauges.GlossyCircularGauge({
                background : [255, 255, 255, 0],
                color : color,
                id : "gauge_" + item,
                width : 150,
                height : 150,
                value : itemProgress,
                noChange : Login.isLoggedIn(),
                majorTicksInterval : 25
            }, dojo.byId("gaugeDiv_" + item));
            gauge.startup();
```

Cheers,
JP

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v7WwD/1/

```
require(["dojox/dgauges/components/grey/CircularLinearGauge"],

function (CircularLinearGauge) {
var myGauge = new CircularLinearGauge({
    value: 20,
    minimum: 0,
    maximum: 150,
    majorTickInterval: 25,
    minorTickIntervall: 5,
    indicatorColor: "#000080", //Zeiger
    fillColor: "#FFFFFF"
}, dojo.byId("gauge"));
myGauge.startup();
});

//more code in the fiddle
//......
```

I have created a CircularLinearGauge programatically.

Regards

Comment: this was very helpful for me, but doesnt work in Internet Explorer 8. Do you know why? Is there a fix?

Comment: well, i got a fix using my own indexOf. This example finally works in ie8: http://jsfiddle.net/MacroX/v7WwD/3/ If you have a better idea please tell me

Comment: Sorry for my third consecutive comment, but I noticed that the ovals in ie8 look terrible, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi Michael! No Problem, but what do you mean with ovals?

Comment: The CircularRangeIndicator, this looks bad in ie8 (sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

First I would consider using dojox/dgauges (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/dgauges.html) instead of dojox/gauges. These are the only well maintained gauges in the toolkit as of today. Second with dojox/dgauges you can set the snapInterval of your LinearScaler to 25 and you should get the expected behavior.

Comment: Hey Christophe. I've tried using a dgauge instead but can't seem to create one programatically. I've tried requiring and usnig dojox/dgauges/components/default/CircularLinearGauge and dojox/dgauges/CircularGauge. I can't find an example anywhere. Do you have some working code you code share?